# Doctrine, how to left join an entity which wasn't generated?

Tags: php, entity-framework, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have rights:

```
CREATE TABLE `rights` (
    `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `U_name` (`name`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

and profiles:

```
CREATE TABLE `profile` (
    `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `U_name` (`name`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

I want to connect `profiles` to `rights` and also profiles to profiles:

```
CREATE TABLE `profile_profile` (
    `profile_id1` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `profile_id2` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`profile_id1`, `profile_id2`),
    INDEX `I_profile_id2` (`profile_id2`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_profile_profile-profile-1` FOREIGN KEY (`profile_id1`) REFERENCES `profile` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT `FK_profile_profile-profile-2` FOREIGN KEY (`profile_id2`) REFERENCES `profile` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `profile_right` (
    `profile_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `right_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`profile_id`, `right_id`),
    INDEX `I_right_id` (`right_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_profile_right-profile` FOREIGN KEY (`profile_id`) REFERENCES `profile` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT `FK_profile_right-rights` FOREIGN KEY (`right_id`) REFERENCES `rights` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

a better overview:[image]

so I generate entities:

> php apps/doctrine.php dev orm:generate-entities libs/ --no-backup
>   --extend="\Doctrine\Entity\BaseEntity"

here come the problems. The `Profile` and `Rights` entities gets created, while `Profile_rights` and `Profile_profile` not. How to use them then?

Comment: What do you want to use them for?

Comment: I want to get rights of a profile, for example

Comment: and what about if I just want to insert a new entry?

Comment: Profile_rights and Profile_profile are not really entities, your entities are Profile and Right and they have associations. When using an ORM we talk about objects and associated, related objects and object references not tables and plain join tables have no meaning in the ORM world. You should read the Doctrine docs first and learn how it works and you will find there how to write queries as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In doctrine, join tables are not represented by an Entity.

You can find a `@ORM\ManyToMany` in your entities, with a `@ORM\JoinTable` and all informations about your associations.
This is the representation of your join table(s), use getters and setters like said by @Richard to access them.

Get more informations in the [Associations mapping](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html) (to see all kind of associations) and [Working with associations](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html) (to learn how work with them) chapters of the documentation.

Hope you have a good experience with doctrine.

**EDIT**

After look more at your UML, at least one of your associations doesn't need a many-to-many (As said by the first answer), but if they really have join tables in SQL, and you imported them by reverse engineering, they will surely be exactly as they are in SQL (a many-to-many with join table).

Comment: is it a big sin if I manually create entities/repository for them?

Comment: It would be useless. Use associations like I explained is the only way to manage foreign keys correctly in doctrine. Otherwise, it's not doctrine. But don't worry ! It's a very intuitive tool, you will learn it easily.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to access the joining entity on a ManyToMany relationship you need to break it down to a OneToMany, ManyToOne.

E.g.

Profile - OneToMany < ProfileRight > ManyToOne - Profile.

Whether you should is another question. You **only** need to do this if you want to store extra data on the join table.

With what you have there it's trivial to get rights for a profile. For any profile you have loaded you simply call

```
 $profile->getRights()
```

and doctrine will (assuming your generated entity mappings are correct) transparently fetch all the associated Rights entities for you based on the join table.

Similarly if you add a Right to a profile:

```
$right = new Right();
$profile->addRight($right);
```

Doctrine will transparently add the join table entry for you.

Comment: is it a big sin if I manually create entities/repository for them?

Comment: There's nothing stopping you, however like I said there is no real point unless you wish to store additional data on the join table. Additionally you'll need to change the type of relations in your entities. I don't recommend it unless you fit the extra data scenario as it's pretty pointless otherwise.

Comment: As @chalasr says give it a chance & don't fight the ORM, it's really very good at what it does.